# WPF: Modify line spacing of Word document in RTB

Tags: wpf, line, spacing

I am giving the user the possibility to load several text file formats into a RichTextBox.

Furthermore I don't want line spacing, so I added a style into the XAML:

```
<RichTextBox .....>
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```

This works fine for all documents except Word documents. The line spacing of the Word document remains in my RichTextBox. I tried the following lines of code that I found on the web, but it makes the text disappear at the top of the RichTextBox and also blends into the next line:

```
rtb2Document.SetValue(Paragraph.LineStackingStrategyProperty, LineStackingStrategy.BlockLineHeight);
rtb2Document.SetValue(Paragraph.LineHeightProperty, 10.0);
```

Any ideas how I can eliminate the line spacing for MS Word document with high line spacing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by modifying each Block. If there is a better solution, don't hesitate to let me know. Here's mine:

```
foreach (Block blCurrentBlock in rtb2Document.Document.Blocks)
{
    Paragraph p = blCurrentBlock as Paragraph;
    p.Margin = new Thickness(0);
}
```